The answer is in the middle
The answer is in the middle and, purportedly, is (5 7, 5 6).
Method used to digitize text  
Nintendo game console  
SF term for impossibly fast spaceship travel  
Product used to change hair color  
Tool used to punch holes  
Disappeared  
Head honcho in IT  
Question often asked by children  
Base SI units of mass  
X  
One of the Three Stooges  
Org. for Tiger Woods  
Attribute of an HTML image tag designating location  
Type of bar found atop many webpages, for short  
Measure of academic success  
Archaic term for siemens  
U.S. agency associated with espionage  
Mechanical puzzle org. founded by Ron van Bruchem and Tyson Mao  
U.S. stock ticker of global hamburger franchise  
Word often seen on a bathroom door  
Hotel  
Country south of CHE  
Largest art museum in the U.S.  
Pirate affirmative  
Suggest someone for an Oscar, for short  
AFC counterpart  
Texting shorthand to decline an offer  
Airport in Okha, Russia  
Author of the U.S. national anthem  
Attire for a big day  
Unaffiliated politician; e.g. neither DEM nor GOP  
By way of  
Alps or Pyrenees, e.g.  
Originally named  
Cutting tool similar to an axe  
American federal government agency in charge of finances  
Indicating an unspecified instance in a series  
Garfield or Tom, for example  
HIV or syphilis, e.g.  
Meadow, often poetically  
Land of fire and ice  
Land to which Cain was exiled  
Formal process or doc used to gather initial knowledge from a business or vendor  
Type of tree used by Thorin for defense  
Number associated with Dave, Frank and HAL, in Rome  
Antarctic glacier located between the Hamrane Heights and Robin Heights  
Boat for Noah  
Research and development agency within the U.S. DOJ  
Island ctry with three green diamonds on its flag  
Windows file format developed in 1991 for sound media  


Are we talking about

 Lebanon, Kansas?

Seems likely, because it would definitely be in the middle, and combining all the "middles" of the answers

 OCR - Method used to digitize text
WII - Nintendo game console
FTL - SF term for impossibly fast spaceship travel
DYE - Product used to change hair color
AWL - Tool used to punch holes
HID - Disappeared
CTO - Head honcho in IT
WHY - Question often asked by children
KGS - Base SI units of mass
TEN - X
MOE - One of the Three Stooges
PGA - Org. for Tiger Woods
SRC - Attribute of an HTML image tag designating location
NAV - Type of bar found atop many webpages, for short
GPA - Measure of academic success
MHO - Archaic term for siemens
CIA - U.S. agency associated with espionage
WCA - Mechanical puzzle org. founded by Ron van Bruchem and Tyson Mao
MCD - U.S. stock ticker of global hamburger franchise
MEN - Word often seen on a bathroom door
INN - Hotel
ITA - Country south of CHE
MET - Largest art museum in the U.S.
ARR - Pirate affirmative
NOM - Suggest someone for an Oscar, for short
NFC - AFC counterpart
_T_ - Texting shorthand to decline an offer
OHH - Airport in Okha, Russia
KEY - Author of the U.S. national anthem
TUX - Attire for a big day
IND - Unaffiliated politician; e.g. neither DEM nor GOP
VIA - By way of
_T_ - Alps or Pyrenees, e.g.
NEE - Originally named
ADZ - Cutting tool similar to an axe
_S_ - American federal government agency in charge of finances
NTH - Indicating an unspecified instance in a series
CAT - Garfield or Tom, for example
STD - HIV or syphilis, e.g.
_E_ - Meadow, often poetically
ISL - Land of fire and ice
NOD - Land to which Cain was exiled
RFI - Formal process or doc used to gather initial knowledge from a business or vendor
OAK - Type of tree used by Thorin for defense
MMI - Number associated with Dave, Frank and HAL, in Rome
HEI - Antarctic glacier located between the Hamrane Heights and Robin Heights
ARK - Boat for Noah
NIJ - Research and development agency within the U.S. DOJ
VCT - Island ctry with three green diamonds on its flag
WAV - Windows file format developed in 1991 for sound media

we don't find an answer, but a new question instead:

 CITY WITH GEOGRAPHIC CENTER OF THE UNITED STATES OF AMERICA

 (Some of the answers are still missing, but we're well within the unicity distance, so we can guess the rest of the letters without any danger of being wrong)

And although there are several alternative definitions giving different answers, the one mentioned at the top seems to be the one that fits the letter count (7,6) given.

Some of your missing ones: rot13(AGL = Ab gunax lbh, ZGF = zbhagf, YRN = zrnqbj)

Can you spot the pattern that will yield the remaining answers?

It will also fix a wrong item.

So sorry, I had the wrong enumeration for the final answer, I think it's fixed now. These two answers are essentially there, just need one finished end to end.

+1 Lebanon, Kansas
There are 50 lines representing the 50 United States. The first and last letter make up state abbreviations.
Correction:
MIA - Disappeared
Filling in the blanks:
NTY - Texting shorthand to decline an offer
MTS - Alps or Pyrenees, e.g.
UST - American federal government agency in charge of finances
LEA - Meadow, often poetically

Welcome to Puzzling.SE! This should be an edit to the existing answer, rather than an answer in its own right.

Great job! I wish I could award both answers a green check. If you reference/include/cite the work from Bass's partial answer so that this is a full write-up, then I would say this deserves the green check, as they did the 'easy' work but you solved/proved/completed the overall puzzle. Otherwise, if Bass fixes their post first, then they can have it - as it stands, I feel like I am seeing two incomplete solutions.

So sorry, I had the wrong enumeration for the final answer, I think it's fixed now. These two answers are essentially there, just need one finished end to end.
